# VLC freezes with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: grub2, vlc

I read [this post](https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=56536) about that subject and I tried the solution proposed by xuxu, but when I type in a terminal:

```
gksudo gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst
```

it does not work and I get the answer :

```
Command 'gksudo' not found, did you mean:
  command 'gfsudo' from deb gfarm-client
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: `gksudo` is not available anymore on Ubuntu 18.04. Use `sudo -i` instead. (French: `gksudo` n'est plus disponible pour Ubuntu 18.04. Veuillez utiliser `sudo -i`.